# Trouble clustering tweets data

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use k-means clustering to get some idea about the subjects of a number of tweets. I've written the following code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import json
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean


with open("tweets.json",'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.readline())
noise = '|'.join(['%','#','@','RT','&amp', r'(?:(?:\d+,?)+(?:\.?\d+)?)',r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&amp;+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]))+'])

#for item in data:
#    print(item['text'].strip('@'))
filtered_data = []
for tweet in data:
    filtered_data.append(re.sub(noise, "", tweet['text']))

X = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english').fit_transform(filtered_data)

disortions = []
K = range(1, 10)

kmeanmod = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)

for k in K:
    kmeanmod = KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(X)
    kmeanmod.fit(X)
    a = np.array(X)
    print(a.shape)

    b = np.array(kmeanmod.cluster_centers_)
    disortions.append(sum(np.min(euclidean(np.array(a), b))))
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error:

```
raise NotImplementedError('adding a nonzero scalar to a '
NotImplementedError: adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not supported
```

I can't find out about the cause of this error, and when I change

```
disortions.append(sum(np.min(euclidean(np.array(a), b))))
```

into

```
disortions.append(sum(np.min(cdist(np.array(a), b))))
```

I get this error:

```
raise ValueError('XA must be a 2-dimensional array.')
ValueError: XA must be a 2-dimensional array.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you get when you do print(a.shape)? Output of tfidfVectorizer is a sparse matrix, so either you convert that to a dense array before applying your logic or use scipy to merge the values instead of numpy.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thank you for your comment! Could you explain more elaborate how I would do so?